# vaadin-grid selection not working

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid

The row selection is not working for me. The selectedItems array only changes if I select everything at once. I am not sure if I got something wrong or if that is a bug.

> selectedItems: An array that contains the selected items.
>   https://www.webcomponents.org/element/vaadin/vaadin-grid/elements/vaadin-grid

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-selection-column.html">

<dom-module id="schedule-vaadin-test">

    <template>

        <vaadin-grid id="material" aria-label="Array Data Example" items="[[items]]" selected-items="{{selectedItems}}">

            <vaadin-grid-selection-column auto-select>
            </vaadin-grid-selection-column>

            <vaadin-grid-column width="50px" flex-grow="0">
                <template class="header">#</template>
                <template>[[index]]</template>
            </vaadin-grid-column>

            <vaadin-grid-column>
                <template class="header">First Name</template>
                <template>[[item.firstName]]</template>
            </vaadin-grid-column>

            <vaadin-grid-column>
                <template class="header">Last Name</template>
                <template>[[item.lastName]]</template>
            </vaadin-grid-column>

        </vaadin-grid>
    </template>

    <script>
        /**
         * @customElement
         * @polymer
         */
        class ScheduleVaadinTest extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() {
                return 'schedule-vaadin-test';
            }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    items: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: [{"firstName":"Foo", "lastName":"Bar"},
                                {"firstName":"Foo", "lastName":"Bar"},
                                {"firstName":"Foo", "lastName":"Bar"}]
                    },

                    selectedItems: {
                        type: Array,
                        observer: 'selectedItemsChanged'
                    }
                };
            }

            static get observers() {
                return []
            }

            selectedItemsChanged() {
                console.log(this.selectedItems);
            }
        }

        customElements.define(ScheduleVaadinTest.is, ScheduleVaadinTest);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Complex observers are declared in the observers array. Complex observers can monitor one or more paths. These paths are called the observer's dependencies.

I just forgot to use a complex observer. I am not sure why the objects changes twice on selection. I am going to updated this answer as soon as I know.

[**EDIT**: Observer is changed to observe [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) only. The value of the array is not changing twice but is printing on console twice since you were using a wildcard(*) observer. That called the observer first when it observed splices and then when it observed change in length of the array. ]

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-selection-column.html">

<dom-module id="schedule-vaadin-test">

    <template>

        <vaadin-grid id="material" aria-label="Array Data Example" items="[[items]]" selected-items="{{selectedItems}}">

            <vaadin-grid-selection-column>
            </vaadin-grid-selection-column>

            <vaadin-grid-column width="50px" flex-grow="0">
                <template class="header">#</template>
                <template>[[index]]</template>
            </vaadin-grid-column>

            <vaadin-grid-column>
                <template class="header">First Name</template>
                <template>[[item.firstName]]</template>
            </vaadin-grid-column>

            <vaadin-grid-column>
                <template class="header">Last Name</template>
                <template>[[item.lastName]]</template>
            </vaadin-grid-column>

        </vaadin-grid>
    </template>

    <script>
        /**
         * @customElement
         * @polymer
         */
        class ScheduleVaadinTest extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() {
                return 'schedule-vaadin-test';
            }

            static get properties() {
                return {
                    items: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: [{"firstName":"Foo1", "lastName":"Bar1"},
                                {"firstName":"Foo2", "lastName":"Bar2"},
                                {"firstName":"Foo3", "lastName":"Bar3"}]
                    },
                    /*activeItem: {
                        type: Array,
                        observer: '_activeItemChanged'
                    },--this is not being used*/

                    selectedItems: {
                        type: Array
                    }
                };
            }

            static get observers() {
                return [
                    //'_selectedItemsChanged(selectedItems.*)'
                      '_selectedItemsChanged(selectedItems.splices)'
                ]
            }

            _selectedItemsChanged() {
                console.log(this.selectedItems);
            }
        }

        customElements.define(ScheduleVaadinTest.is, ScheduleVaadinTest);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for you:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
```

```
<template>

    <vaadin-grid id="material" aria-label="Array Data Example" items="[[items]]" selected-items={{selectedItems}} active-item="{{selectedItem}}">

        <vaadin-grid-selection-column auto-select>
        </vaadin-grid-selection-column>

        <vaadin-grid-column width="50px" flex-grow="0">
            <template class="header">#</template>
            <template>[[index]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>

        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">First Name</template>
            <template>[[item.firstName]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>

        <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Last Name</template>
            <template>[[item.lastName]]</template>
        </vaadin-grid-column>

    </vaadin-grid>
</template>

<script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class ScheduleVaadinTest extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'schedule-vaadin-test';
        }

        static get properties() {
            return {
                items: {
                    type: Array,
                    value: [{"firstName":"Foo", "lastName":"Bar"},
                        {"firstName":"Foo2", "lastName":"Bar2"},
                        {"firstName":"Foo3", "lastName":"Bar3"}]
                },
                selectedItem: {
                    type: Array,
                }
                ,
                selectedItems: {
                    type: Array,
                }
            };
        }

        static get observers() {
            return ['_selectedItemsChanged(selectedItem, selectedItems)'];
        }

         _selectedItemsChanged(selectedItem, selectedItems){
            console.log(selectedItems);
        }
    }

    customElements.define(ScheduleVaadinTest.is, ScheduleVaadinTest);
</script>
```

I have added the **activeItem** property that will hold the item user has last interacted with. Also, the observer is changed to observe both single or multiple changes.

Comment: When a row is clicked, the item object from that row is assigned to activeItem. Your solution works as long as auto-select is enabled and the user is clicking the row to select it. Using the check boxes doesn't work because the activeItem doesn't change. If you select an item using the checkbox and another one using the row the selectedItems array is still correct.